# Get Parent form Id of a Button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next buttons in my page. each button are under a form. when next button click i want to pass value.these value may change based on a form. i have tried this code but it cant pass diffrent value.
Button

```
 <input  class="btn btn-danger next child" type="button" value="Next">
```

jquery code is.

```
$('.child').click(function(){
  var id=$(this).parents('form:eq(0)').attr('id');
  let myForm = document.getElementById(id);
        let formData = new FormData(myForm);
        for (var value of formData.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }
});
```

i want like this

```
 <input  class="btn btn-danger next child" type="button" value="Next"  onClick="next(id,1)">
```

how to write function to access parent of this form?

Comment: Do all inputs have a similar class name?

Comment: only buttons  have sama class name.i have  many tabs and  forms and have same button.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('inputId').forEach(function(item.index){ item.parentNode.value// this access form which is the parent of input   and for accessing the parent of form use this item.parentNode.parentNode.value  });

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$('.child').click(function(){
  var id=$(this).closest('form').attr('id');
  let myForm = document.getElementById(id);
        let formData = new FormData(myForm);
        for (var value of formData.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }
});
```

Comment: i have some call like this.here i want diffrent prompt inside click. so can i pass value with click function so based on value i can give diffrent message $(div_id).find(".child").trigger('click')

Comment: Do you want to get some value on the click of a button?